# How to use the "removed" elements after std::remove_if

Tags: c++, stl

Say we've got:

```
struct IsEven {
   bool operator() (int i) { return i % 2 == 0; }
};
```

Then:

```
vector<int> V; // fill with ints
vector<int>::iterator new_end = remove_if(V.begin(), V.end(), IsEven());
V.erase(new_end, V.end());
```

works fine (it leaves `V` with only the odd integers). But it seems that the elements from `new_end` to `V.end()` are *not* the even integers that we're deleting. For example, if `v` starts out as `1 4 2 8 5 7`, then I'm getting `8 5 7` for those elements (although after the `erase` call, the vector indeed has `1 5 7` left).

Apparently, (according to http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/remove_if.html)

```
The iterators in the range [new_last, last) are all still dereferenceable,
but the elements that they point to are unspecified.
```

First of all, WTF? And second, how do I get around this without essentially reimplementing `remove_if`?

Comment: A related tip in case you're using a container of pointers - use partition if you want to delete using the pointers: http://www.ddj.com/architect/184401414

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use `partition()` to partition the vector into groups of odd values at the start and even values at the end.  `partition()` will return an iterator to the first element of the second grouping.

As for the WTF, I'm not sure why you would expect a remove operation to preserve the elements you want to remove by copying them (that's extra work) to the end of the container.
Most people consider the WTF in `remove()` (and it's cousins) to be the fact that the size of the vector is not reduced and you have to call `erase()` to actually delete undesired elements after the remove operation.

Comment: That actually was my initial WTF, but I've gotten used to it, and I didn't realize that partition() existed.

Comment: It makes sense when you think about it though. An iterator only represents a sequence within a container, not the container itself.
It may not represent every element in the container, or data in a container at all.

But yes, it often trips newbies up. And then they have an a-ha moment and *get* STL

Comment: jalf is right.  It's confusing initially, but if remove_if() was able to get rid of the remaining elements itself, that would mean that it could not work with arrays.  (How do you "delete elements from" an array?)

Comment: Yeah, I get that. I just assumed remove_if did what partition actually does. My problem was that the SGI site doesn't reference partition (from the remove_if page) so I had no way of finding it (or knowing that such a thing exists).

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the point is that the function is called `remove_if` for a reason. It removes elements. It doesn't move them or select them. After you've called remove_if, you're no longer guaranteed that the elements you removed exist. All you're guaranteed is that the elements between `first` and `new_last` do not contain any of the removed elements.

`std::partition` would be a better choice, wouldn't it? Or perhaps `remove_copy_if`, depending on exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use the "removed" elements, you want [std::partition](http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibref/partition.html).